# Automatically organize views in relative layout | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to auto-organize views in the layout. 
It must be by code, because I have a button to add more views.

I need that the views put at the rigth of other view if the window have place.
Else, it must put bellow the first view.

I use a relative layout, but if there are a better way...

[A exaple like i want to organize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3FHE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [Flexbox Layout library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) from Google. It is tailor-made to lay views out in a line, but wrap to the next line if there isn't room for the next view.

Once you've added this library to your app, you'd use a `FlexboxLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout` as your root view.

Comment: hey! I have another problem, can u help me?

Comment: I’m happy to try, but the best thing to do would be to ask a new question, and I (and everyone else) can try to answer that there.